# Change of variables for a double integral formula

Tags: calculus, integration

I would like to understand the following formula:

> $$\int \int_D f(x,y)\;dx\:dy=\int\int_Rf(x(u,v),y(u,v)) \left|
>  \begin{array}{cc} x_u & x_v  \\ y_u & y_v  \\  \end{array}
>  \right|\;du\:dv,$$

where we have changed from XY-coordinates to UV-coordinates. Where does the determinant term (Jacobian) come from? Proof?

Comment: hmmm why not look in a book or a script to learn something about such a general topic ...
http://www-astro.physics.ox.ac.uk/~sr/lectures/multiples/Lecture5reallynew.pdf

Comment: If you've taken linear algebra, you might remember that determinants represent how much areas (or volumes) are scaled by under a transformation. You can imagine that this would be important for integrating over an area.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The idea behind the Jacobian is that it is a kind of an analogue to $\frac{dx}{du}$ when you perform a one dimensional change of variables.

When you integrate the first integral you integrate over area elements with size $dx \cdot dy$. Subsequently you're integrating over area elements $du \cdot dv$. These need not be the same size as the original ones and the Jacobian accounts for the difference between them.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose, your function $f$ is constant, say, 4. If that Jacobain term were not there, you would get 4 times area of $D$ on the left, and 4 times area of $R$ on the right. But the areas of D and R can be really different. The simplest case you can think is that R is a copy of D but dilated to twice its size. This explains why you should consider how the area varies when shifting from D-regions to R-regions. Since, f in general is not constant and its behavior is unique around every single point, you need to do this analysis on infinitesimally small regions around each point. That Jacobian is precisely the answer to this! -- Draw pictures!!